2d map of the world resolution (resolution problem and its effect on image quality when zooming.)
I'm developing a 2D grand strategy game in the style of Age of History and Paradox games using Godot v4. My current map creation method involves creating a background PNG image of the world map with superimposed textures and colors for each country. On top of this, I layer each country individually as transparent vector svg files within the engine.
The problem is that to maintain clarity and prevent pixelation when zooming in, I need an extremely large map size - over 16000x11000px. Even Godot struggles to handle such a massive image. With a smaller resolution, everything becomes blurry when the camera zooms in. [
Is there a way to create a clear and detailed map without relying on such a huge image size? Perhaps my approach is fundamentally flawed, and there's a better solution?

The approach I would recommend is, instead of having one big sprite, we slice it and make a grid of smaller sprites.
I don't know exactly how you structured the scene, but the generic steps to follow are:

Load the original map using Image.load_from_file().
Calculate the number of slices you need.
Cut slices (not greater than 4096x4096, I suggest 512x512) calling Image.get_region(my_slice_coordinates) on the original image.
For each slice image generate a mipmap calling Image.generate_mipmaps().
For each slice image generate a slice texture calling ImageTexture.create_from_image(my_slice_image).
For each slice texture create a sprite node setting the correct coordinates in the scene.


"Yes, it worked, but I have another question. When a player looks at the map from a distance, one general texture is visible, but when approaching certain areas of the map, the texture changes to a more detailed one. Accordingly, for a more detailed map, I will have, for example, 9 textures created by the method you described. The question is how to make Godot load only the texture that the player is looking at. Basically, I need to create LOD (Level of Detail) for texture.

Mipmaps are the LOD of textures. If you need to access then in a shader, you use functions like textureLod().

If you generated the mipmaps, the texture has LOD, and you are good to go, the engine will handle it for you automatically. Also, if the answer is correct, don't forget to mark it as accepted.

Thank you) It is working just fine)

The maximum image size is determined by the video card capabilities and software interface/drivers.
You must replace the textures at certain zoom levels.
The question is how portable does your game need to be?
A 4k texture is the maximum size for almost all modern video cards/platforms.

This is a PC game. So, I need to create one texture for the overall map when the camera is zoomed out, and several textures, for example, 4, for each individual section of the map that the player will see when zoomed in. The remaining question is how to implement this in Godot))

This was posted as an answer, but it reads like more of a comment.

@АрсенИсаченко Yes, 4k should work for current PC platforms. For implementation you will need to edit your question and provide the texture load and zoom code.

@Pikalek OP asked a conceptual question and got a conceptual answer.  The question in my answer is mostly rhetorical(4k max but leaves the option for 2k open if needed).  My answer describes the underlying reason for the problem, presents a solution(the optimal transition levels would need to be worked out based on the final size) and suggests an optimal maximum size. The only element that is missing is code, but if there is no code in the question, then no code in the answer. If expansion is needed, the OP can ask, as they have done here. I look at all questions as broader than needs of OP.
